# cannot create a virtual machine in virt-manager

Tags: kvm-virtualization, virt-manager

I got the following message when creating a virtual machine in virt-manager:

```
Error launching manager: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_default_storage_format'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/engine.py", line 889, in _do_show_create
    self._get_create_dialog().show(src.topwin, uri)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/create.py", line 170, in show
    self.reset_state(uri)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/create.py", line 393, in reset_state
    self.addstorage.reset_state()
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/addstorage.py", line 196, in reset_state
    fmt = self.conn.get_default_storage_format()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_default_storage_format'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found that the package `qemu-system` was missing.

Answer (score 1):

This bug already opened on the launchpad:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virt-manager/+bug/1448631